# Datepicker disables previous and future dates wrong

Tags: javascript, forms, datepicker

I've created a datepicker for my form and it selects the current date and disables past dates.

```js
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: false,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  minDate: dateToday,
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
          instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
          date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
      dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="from" name="FechaLlegada" class="campo" placeholder="Llegada" focusOnShow="false" ignoreReadonly="true" readonly="true">

<input type="text" id="to" name="FechaSalida" class="campo" placeholder="Salida" focusOnShow="false" ignoreReadonly="true" readonly="true">
```

But the problem is that when I select a "from" date and then a "to" date, my "to" date block my "from" date. So for example if I select "from" 10 july "to" 15 july, then I can't change my from date anymore after 15 july. It blocks me future dates after the "to" date selected.

Is like if I select the "to" date it makes it the maxDate until I reload the page.

How can I prevent this maxDate so I can always select the date I want? The only restriction I need is to disable past dates from today date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code**

Removed code setting `maxDate` for `from` datepicker

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: false,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  minDate: dateToday,
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : null,
      instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
     if(option!==null){
         dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
      }
  }
});
```

```js
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: false,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  minDate: dateToday,
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : null,
      instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
      if(option!==null){
      dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="text" id="from" name="FechaLlegada" class="campo" placeholder="Llegada" focusOnShow="false" ignoreReadonly="true" readonly="true">

<input type="text" id="to" name="FechaSalida" class="campo" placeholder="Salida" focusOnShow="false" ignoreReadonly="true" readonly="true">
```

Comment: Glad to help you:) Happy coding-:)-:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about jquery 2.1.1 and jquery-ui 1.12.1 as described in [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) you should consider the [destroy method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy) to re-elaborate `minDate` and `maxDate` options - but that would be tricky. So i would consider to use a [timerange datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) in this case to get the desidered result.

```js
   $(function () {
var dateToday = new Date();
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    from = $("#from")
        .datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: false,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: dateToday
        })
        .on("change", function () {
            to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
        }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3
    })
        .on("change", function () {
            from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
        });

function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
        date = null;
    }

    return date;
}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="from" name="FechaLlegada" class="campo" placeholder="Llegada" focusOnShow="false" ignoreReadonly="true" readonly="true">

<input type="text" id="to" name="FechaSalida" class="campo" placeholder="Salida" focusOnShow="false" ignoreReadonly="true" readonly="true">
```

Comment: That works great, but notice that the moment you select the "to" date then the "from" date is restricted and I can't pick any future date above "to" date I've selected. The moment when I pick a date in the second form, it restricts the first form maxDate.

Comment: because that's how a time range works: from --> to. So you would like to be able to posticipate 'from' to 'to'?

Comment: Yes, what I need is to disable maxDate range. What I did with @Amal's solution is to put null instead maxDate and works great now. Thanks Paolo for your approach!